# Using apt why do I get file 'network_proxy.conf' in directory '/etc/apt/preferences.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt-get, apt

I get the following warning when I try to install packages.

```
N: Ignoring file 'network_proxy.conf' in directory '/etc/apt/preferences.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

Using apt why do I get file `network_proxy.conf` in directory `/etc/apt/preferences.d/` as it has an invalid filename extension

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt_preferences.5.en.html)

**TLDR**
Files need to have the following

**extension:**
 - `.pref`
 - or no extension

**filename:**
  - contain letters (a-z and A-Z)
  - digits (0-9)
  - underscore (_)
  - hyphen (-)
  - period (.)

[preferences.d](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt_preferences.5.en.html)
Note that the files in the /etc/apt/preferences.d directory are parsed in alphanumeric ascending order and need to obey the following naming convention: The files have either no or "pref" as filename extension and only contain alphanumeric, hyphen (-), underscore (_) and period (.) characters. Otherwise APT will print a notice that it has ignored a file, unless that file matches a pattern in the Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently configuration list - in which case it will be silently ignored.

I fixed this by renaming `network_proxy.conf` to `network_proxy.pref`